# XAML equivalent to DIV in HTML?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

What I want to be more specific is an element I can use for grouping a set of other elements, without effecting their layout. The only thing it should do besides giving a nicer XAML by grouping related elements in their own parent tag is to propagate ambient properties such as DataContext. It should be a purely logical element without any visual. Is there something in WPF/XAML intended to be used like this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's no direct equivalent of HTML's `<div>` in WPF/XAML, however, it sounds like the closest thing is WPF's [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx) Class:

> Provides a base class for all Panel
>   elements. Use Panel elements to
>   position and arrange child objects in
>   Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)
>   applications.

However, the `Panel` class is an abstract class which cannot be instantiated directly, and can only be used by utilising one of the non-abstract derivations within the WPF framework.  These include:

> Canvas, DockPanel, Grid, TabPanel,
>   ToolBarOverflowPanel, UniformGrid,
>   StackPanel, VirtualizingPanel,
>   WrapPanel

From what you are trying to achieve, the closest of these to your needs would probably be either the [`Canvas`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx) or [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) classes.

If neither of these classes are appropriate, you are always free to implement your own class deriving from the `Panel` class.

Bear in mind, though, that all of these classes (including the base `Panel` class) are, by their very nature, UI-specific (i.e. they are intended to be visual elements rather than purely logical) although they can be configured to have little or no *visible* visual element to them.  This is entirely by design in WPF as the [Wikipedia article on XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xaml) correctly states:

> In WPF, XAML is used as a **user interface** markup language to define UI
>   elements, data binding, eventing, and
>   other features.

Comment: I got that far as to Panel as well. Using any of the existing non-abstract variant will however change the layout if the child elements use the same type of panel (i e Grid.Row="0" on child elements will start to mean something else if I use Grid). I guess the thing to do is to implement my own class deriving from Panel.

Answer (score 1):

XAML, unlike HTML, does not claim to be "semantic" - it's a presentation technology and it knows it's a presentation technology, there are no XAML elements that only exist to make the markup look nicer without changing the display.

You can't implement a WPF element like you want because any change to the structure of the XAML will change the layout, for example, a Grid (like all panels) will arrange it's direct children - the moment you group some of those children inside another element the Grid will layout that element as a single unit and not each of it's children individually.

This makes sense if you think of XAML as a way to fill .net objects, a Grid has a Children property, that property is a list, and it will layout the items of that list.

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio 2019 contains a snippet for collapsible region tags.
You can access this by typing `#region` and hitting tab twice.

It enters the following lines of code:

```xml
<!--#region MyRegion-->
<MyComponent />
<MyComponent />
<!--#endregion-->
```

It sounds like this is the tag you were looking for. As it is a comment tag, it doesn't allow any special interaction, so it won't propagate ambient properties unfortunately.

It does allow you to collapse the region in VS though.

Comment: OP is asking for a XAML element similar to a `div`; not a way to collapse code blocks in dev.